# What do you call the number k, that you must multiply with x, in order to get y?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, fractions

In the equation:

$$y = kx$$

The coefficient or constant $k$, represents how many multiples of $x$ are required to equal $y$.

What is the term for $k$, in that it represents the quotient of $y/x$?

If we were looking at $y:x$, we would call that the ratio of $y$ and $x$.

Similarly if we had $y/x$, we would call that the _____ of $y$ and $x$.

I tried to Google this term for 10 minutes before giving up in the floods of children's math websites and colloquial english usage of the words "fraction", "ratio", etc.

Comment: If $y=kx$ is the equation of a line plotted on the $x$-$y$ plane, then $k$ is the gradient of the line. Otherwise you could just say that $k$ is $y/x$, or the quotient of $y$ and $x$, as you have done in your question.

Comment: "Quotient" is also an appropriate word for the value you get from a division operation. (Just like the sum of $a$ and $b$ is $a+b$.)

Comment: proportionality coefficient

Answer (score 3):

In this context where
$$
y=kx,
$$
we say $y$ is *proportional to* $x$ with a [coefficient of proportionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)) equal to $k$ (see link for other widely used names). In some cases the value of $k$ is not important and we simple write
$$
y\propto x,
$$
which simply reads "*$y$ is proportional to $x$*".

Comment: If you're around, we've got another word search going on in the Cafe chatroom!

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be linear function, i.e.
\begin{align}
f(x) = kx,
\end{align}
for some $k\in\mathbb{R}$. $k$ is sometimes called the **slope** of $f$.